# Element floats according to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how can make make an ELEMENT float according to scroll .
For example , when I scroll down , the element that is `position:fixed` and `left:0` will slowly come down into viewable top left area.

Can this be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the floating type of menu/bar you are searching for is little old style. Why dont you try something like this

Fixed floating elements

http://jsfiddle.net/dueWG/9/

http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/floating

OR take a look at this tutorial

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/

Answer (score 0):

if you need your element to follow the scroll relative to your window you can use

```
position:fixed;
```

instead of absolute;

Comment: ops i wrote wrong . sorry it's position:fixed , thanks for reminding me Headshota

Comment: in this way there wont be any animation kind of thing where his floater slides down. May be this is not what he wants ..